# Spring Boot Thymeleaf not recognizing CSS file

Tags: java, css, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

The problem is that a thymeleaf does not find my css file

Project structure
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMHzK.png)

I am able to access css file with given url http://localhost:8080/styles.css

I use spring boot 3.1.1

I have tried

and

as well as

Template does show correctly but css is not applied

Comment: Things that i have tried

<link href="/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{~/static/styles.css}" />
<link href="/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/static/styles.css}" />
<link href="/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/styles.css}" />

Comment: You need to serve that static css file to the frontend somehow. It won't be magically available just because it's in the resources folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct syntax in your case:

```
<link th:href="@{/styles.css}" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: thank you, spring security was the problem in this case

Answer (score 1):

i see you found the solution
I will give some details as i found.

When using thymeleaf, springboot, spring security
thymeleaf cannot access css files because of spring security

```
`@Bean
public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
    return (web) -> web.ignoring().requestMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**");
}`
```

Will solve the problem. It's work for me.